# Why isn't my cell values showing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a vba code here where the last 5 lines wont show up in my Excel spreadsheet.
What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Count and Avg.")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Individual Board Info")
Set ws3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Graph Info")

Dim i As Integer, ii As Integer
Dim a As Integer, b As Integer

a = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
b = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For i = 2 To a
        ws2.Cells(i, 4) = Date - ws2.Cells(i, 3)
Next i

ws1.Cells(1, b + 1) = Date
ws1.Cells(2, b + 1) = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
ws1.Cells(3, b + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws2.Columns(4))
ws1.Cells(4, b + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws2.Columns(4))
ws1.Cells(5, b + 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws2.Columns(4))
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me. Are you able to expand on this VBA, is there another function being called? Try to step through the code using `F8`.

Comment: I suspect you are looking at the wrong place. The `.Cells(1, b + 1)` means the cell at row 1, column b+1. The `.Cells(2, b + 1)` means the cell at row 2, column b+1 and so on.

Comment: Well, I'm currently at row 31 on ws1. So what I'm trying to do is put the current date as the value for "A32" since it's the next row being used. Then the number of entries in ws2 (minus 1 for the title row) for "B32". Then the highest number in column D of ws2 for "C32". Then the lowest number in column D of ws2 for "D32". Then lastly, the average of all entries in column D of ws2 for "E32". I figured D1 of ws2 is the title, so it wouldn't be counted as an integer in the average, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
b = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

This looks like you're trying to get the last used row in ws1, in which case I would advise against using this method as the used range is not necessarily the range that *appears* to be used (i.e. the cells that you can see)

Try using something like this instead:

```
b = ws1.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws1.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,  MatchCase:=False).Row
```

I suspect the used range may be bloated, and therefore your data is actually being written a lot further down in the sheet than you expect.

Comment: That was exactly what was happening. I scrolled down further and saw a lot of entries there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Axel Ritcher in the comments, the `Cells` function takes the following format: `Cells([row reference], [column reference])` you should just need to switch your references around so it would now read:

```
ws1.Cells(b + 1, 1) = Date
ws1.Cells(b + 1, 2) = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
ws1.Cells(b + 1, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(ws2.Columns(4))
ws1.Cells(b + 1, 4) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(ws2.Columns(4))
ws1.Cells(b + 1, 5) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ws2.Columns(4))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new to this. That helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I have not enough reputation to add a comment, but can you do this in the immediate window and post the answer?

    `Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Count and Avg.")
    [Press Enter]
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Individual Board Info")
    [Press Enter]
    ?ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    [Press Enter]
    ?ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    [Press Enter]`